# real-time location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location, mapkit, real-time

I'm developing an app, and I need the map within the application displays people who have this app, you should also see real-time movement of the person, such as application of Apple "Find My iPhone" or "myTaxi "see where all the taxis which run on a map in real time.
To do this I use the MapKit or google maps? (I think the google maps api for javascript)
But I do not know where I go, I would start a

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your idea will be like this :
[image]

Here is some examples that I made myself:

hope it helps you